# How to set custom x, y position of Electron Menu when using BrowserWindow.fromWebContents

Tags: javascript, menu, electron, popup

I'm using `contextBridge` and `contextIsolation` to create a custom context menu on click and I'm using this example from the docs: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/menu.md#render-process

```js
// renderer
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  ipcRenderer.send('show-context-menu')
})

ipcRenderer.on('context-menu-command', (e, command) => {
  // ...
})

// main
ipcMain.on('show-context-menu', (event) => {
  const template = [
    {
      label: 'Menu Item 1',
      click: () => { event.sender.send('context-menu-command', 'menu-item-1') }
    },
    { type: 'separator' },
    { label: 'Menu Item 2', type: 'checkbox', checked: true }
  ]
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template)
  menu.popup(BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender))
})
```

This works but the context menu appears right under the mouse. I want to supply a custom x and y. [In the docs for `menu.popup`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/main/docs/api/menu.md#menupopupoptions), I can set an `x` and `y` property like this:

```
menu.popup({
  window: /* my window object /*,
  x: /* x position */,
  y: /* y position */,
})
```

But I don't know how to add these properties to the object that I get back from `BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)`.

I tried these options:

```js
menu.popup({ ...BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender), x, y } );
// or
const window = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender);
menu.popup({ window, x, y });
```

and I get this error

```
Error processing argument at index 1, conversion failure from 
at EventEmitter.a.popup (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:81:3188)
```

It seems like electron doesn't like converting the results from `BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender)` into an object.

I also tried this, but get the same error.

```js
const window = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender);
window.x = x;
window.y = y;
menu.popup(window);
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the `x` and `y` variables need to be integers and sometimes they were floats. Putting a `Math.round` around `x` and `y` solved the problem. This worked in the end:

```js
const xRound = Math.round(x);
const yRound = Math.round(y);
const window = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender);
menu.popup({ window, x: xRound, y: yRound } );
```